# Lasso regression / SVM convergence CPU -> GPU

Tags: machine-learning, svm, convergence, libsvm, gpu

I have coded a simple supervised ML classification using 10-20K data points for 25 samples. Linear ML models run quickly for example naive Bayes, linear regression and SVM linear on a small multi-core CPU desktop with 8 G RAM via `scikit-learn`.

However, non-linear models for example lasso regression and non-linear SVM via RBF and polynomial kernels "do not converge" within reasonable uptime, i.e. no more than 4 hours uptime.

Three questions:

- is this known behaviour and is there a pattern within the data set types?
- alternatively are their data sets that simply do not converge for non-linear models?
- would it be resolved via GPU *****, such as the NVIDIA machines?

The rationale of the question is being able to justify that a shift onto a cloud platform will deliver the results sought.

***** For example, a GPU accelerated "non-linear" ML model via either:

- [libSVM](https://mklab.iti.gr/results/gpu-accelerated-libsvm/) SVM RBF kernel or;
- [thunderSVM](https://github.com/Xtra-Computing/thundersvm) or possibly;
- [falcon](https://github.com/falkonml/falkon)

***Post question edit***: the above 3 examples are external to `scikit-learn`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Some models are known not to scale well with data (e.g. SVM, Gaussian processes). You can check this by comparing their [big $O$ time complexity](https://www.thekerneltrip.com/machine/learning/computational-complexity-learning-algorithms/) and memory usage.
- GPUs don't magically make arbitrary code faster. For GPUs to help, you would need the code to be written in a way that utilizes GPUs. This would [not be the case for scikit-learn implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41567895/will-scikit-learn-utilize-gpu). For LibSVM there is an [GPU optimized implementation](https://github.com/MKLab-ITI/CUDA), but this means you need to switch to it instead of using the regular LibSVM used by scikit-learn. What often *would* help is switching to a computer with more CPUs and memory (8 GB is not much for many problems), so it still may be the case for switching to the cloud, but not for machines with GPUs, but with more memory and CPUs.
- Convergence is a different story. For example, lasso regression (a linear model, by the way) has no problem with large datasets, but convergence will depend on the choice of hyperparameters (the $\alpha$ penalty in this case).

Comment: Thanks, the links I provided are for non-`scikit-learn` SVM boosted via GPU. I've updated the post to make that clearer. A likely implication from @Tim's answer is this is a RAM-bottleneck and that makes sense. The links to 'big O' and time complexity are cool and represent an alternative explanation which can be diagnosed.